# Web.Api defining optional parameters in route

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes, option-type

What is the correct syntax for defining optional parameters on the Route of a controller endpoint?

```
    [Route("customers/{customerId}/boats/{boatId}/bookings{contractId?}&{startDate?}&{endDate?}&{outOnly?}", Name = "GetBookingsByBoat")]
    [ResponseType(typeof (IEnumerable<BookingSummaryDTO>))]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int customerId, int boatId, int? contractId, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, bool outOnly = false)
    {
```

The above compiles but when I try and call the endpoint using

```
customers/40/boats/24/bookings
```

I get:

```
{"message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}
```

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
    [Route("customers/{customerId}/boats/{boatId}/bookings", Name = "GetBookingsByBoat")]
    [ResponseType(typeof (IEnumerable<BookingSummaryDTO>))]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int customerId, int boatId, int? contractId = null, DateTime? startDate = null, DateTime? endDate = null, bool outOnly = false)
```